# AWS ECS update-service spawns new task but then stops it and remains the previous

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

I am currently trying out how the best practise for updating containers in AWS ECS is.

I have a cluster running in 3 AZs, which contains one task definition which is linked to my desired docker image on AWS ECR.

Based on that definition, i created a service (which also automatically spawns one task). This service is linked to a load balancer for the sake of having a fixed IP i can then link my domain to via A record. This load balancers also includes all of the AZs.

Now, what happens when i update the docker image with a new tag, create a new revision of the service definition on the new image tag and run

```
aws ecs update-service --cluster devCluster --service devTest --force-new-deployment --task-definition test:5
```

it creates a new task and i also see the updated content when i connect to it via the public IP of the task. But on the load balancer DNS and also on the domain that i linked, there is still the old content. And also, after a short time, the task is gone from the task list and only the former one remains which has the old content.

Is there any wrong assumption that i have or is my strategy somehow false?

Comment: It sounds like your new container isn't passing the load balancer health checks, so the load balancer never routes traffic to it, and after a while it is replaced.

Comment: Interesting. Gotta Check that. But actually it is just a dummy Container and i did. not change anything except a text output